# Pods errorin new IDE

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm using Xcode 10 and Cocoapods 1.5.2

I'm trying to install some pod but it shows the following error

```
――― TEMPLATE END
――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D+Unknown+object+version.&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above,
on: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to
properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7697 [closed] [29
comments]    2 weeks ago

 - Pod Update: RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version. Xcode Beta 5    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8003
[closed] [17 comments]    6 weeks ago

 - RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7458 [closed] [15
comments]    30 Jul 2018

and 42 more at:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D%20Unknown%20object%20version.&type=Issues&utf8=✓
```

What does this mean?

Comment: You can try to change your `Project Format` back to `Xcode 8.0` and try pod install again

Comment: wow, such a ridiculous error thanks